# How to EXECUTE dynamic query in WITH clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the my sample query, Can any one suggest me how to EXECUTE dynamic query in WITH clause.

```
DECLARE @V_TBLID NVARCHAR(MAX) = 1, @V_QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @IN_PAGESIZE INT = 5, @IN_PAGEINDEX INT = 1;      
SET @V_QUERY = N'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE'+ @V_TBLID;
WITH RESULTS AS
(
    EXEC(@V_QUERY)
)
SELECT * FROM RESULTS
WHERE [row_num] BETWEEN (((@IN_PAGEINDEX - 1) * @IN_PAGESIZE) + 1) AND (@IN_PAGEINDEX * @IN_PAGESIZE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use EXECUTE inside a CTE.

To do it using the approach you are trying, you'd need to encapsulate the whole query into a dynamic sql statement that builds up the CTE (WITH statement) dynamically, appending @V_QUERY to that dynamic sql statement.

e.g. something like

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 
    'WITH Results AS (' + @V_QUERY + ')
     SELECT * 
     FROM Results
     WHERE [row_num] BETWEEN (((@IN_PAGEINDEX - 1) * @IN_PAGESIZE) + 1) AND (@IN_PAGEINDEX * @IN_PAGESIZE)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@IN_PAGEINDEX INT, @IN_PAGESIZE INT', @IN_PAGEINDEX, @IN_PAGESIZE
```

Obligatory sidenote - wherever using dynamic sql, make sure you guard against SQL injection risks!